# Notification with Timer and Buttons?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm creating something like a timer app with flutter. I want to display a notification while the timer is running that displays the current time and that has a button to cancel/pause the timer.

More precisely I have a Stream that exposes another int value (the time left) every 100 ms. So I would have to subscribe to this Stream in my notification.

I don't really know much about native app developing. I know this is possible for android, I have a similar app installed but is that also possible for iOS? And most importantly is that possible with Flutter with a package or something? I know there are packages for notifications but I haven't really found something for my needs.

Any Ideas? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to solve this. If yes, can you please share your solution